# Prevent on resize event when opens phone keyboard (JS)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, responsive-design, resize

Good day guys, I hope someone knows how I can run a function only when the phone device changes orientation. I mean exactly **ONLY when the phone device changes its orientation**, not when keyboard opens >> this is the problem.

I know this `window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight`, and in conjunction with `resize` event, it gives me what I need: determination landscape and portrait. But I just now tested my website on Android, and when the keyboard opens this gives me a `fake landscape result`, I mean device orientation not was changed for real. So, this is the question, how I can run my function when the phone (Android, iOS) changes its orientation, but prevent it if the orientation changes because of keyboard opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.screen` and all what it gives to you!

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard causes a change in the height of the screen.  If you don't want to, or don't need to handle this, then you can filter out changes to just the width:

```
let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    if (window.innerWidth != windowWidth) {
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        handleEvent();
    }
});
```

Comment: You should also add some explanation of the code, see how do I write a good answer [answer].